# How to add dollar sign to input field without affecting the value of input?

Tags: javascript, html, css, ejs

How can i add $ to the following input:

```
<td class="td10"><input type='text' class='form-control' id="boqRate" name="boq[boqRate]"></td>
```

Comment: Wrap the input box in a `div` and use CSS to create an illusion of having `$` as a prefix in the textbox. Search for the tutorials, there are a lot of those available already. There is no other way, AFAIK.

Answer (score 6):

Try this. I have added span element with `position:absolute`.

```css
.prefix {
  margin-right: -10px;
  position: absolute;
}

.my-input {
  padding-left: 5px;
}
```

```html
<td class="td10"><span class="prefix">$</span><input class="my-input" type='text' class='form-control' id="boqRate" name="boq[boqRate]"></td>
```

Answer (score 1):

This should work:

```js
let input = document.getElementById("name");

input.addEventListener("keydown", () => {
  let inputValue = input.value;
  if (inputValue) {
    if (inputValue.charAt(0) === "$") {
      inputValue = inputValue.substring(1);
    }
  }
  let newValue = `$${inputValue}`;
  input.value = newValue;
});
```

```html
<input id="name" />
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: Press the <shift> key while having the input box focused. If I didn't know about it prior I'd end up having $$.

Comment: It might be better to use `keyup` instead of `keydown`.

Comment: @Barmar could you please elaborate?

Comment: I think that might solve the problem Esaith mentioned, because it runs after the user types a `$`.

Comment: @Barmar maybe but it does create a problem when you press backspace. Try it here: https://jsfiddle.net/m5v1a5q1/ (with keyup)

Comment: Thanks mate. It is actually working but i dont want to change the value of the input. I need to add $ with css/html so it doesn't affect the value